# "Cannot find symbol" class DataSourceBuilder [ERROR] location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I have a legacy Spring Boot project that was using version `1.5.9.RELEASE` and using spring framework version `4.3.13.RELEASE`. I just upgrade the Spring boot to `2.4.4` and I'm using the starter-parent to let it handle dependency version for me.

The only thing now is that I am getting a compilation error when trying to `mvn install`:

```
Cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataSourceBuilder
[ERROR]   location: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc
```

Did I break something by upgrading my dependencies? My project is using `h2`, `hibernate`, `postgresql`, and `hiarkiCP` in the dependencies. I see `spring-boot-autoconfigure` listed in the spring boot starter parent dependencies, so I figured this class was coming from there and I should be importing it anyway, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please share your pom dependencies/dependency management too so we can check which dependencies you have imported. And the complete stack trace of the error too would help.